# python file not found when trying to rename files

Tags: python, file

i'm trying to write a script that goes through the current working directory and all of it's sub directories and changes the file names, here is my code:

```
from os import rename, listdir, getcwd, walk
from os.path import isdir, join

for root, dirs, files in walk(getcwd()):
for name in files:
    rename(join(root, name), join(root, name.replace("Season ", "S")))
    rename(join(root, name), join(root, name.replace("season ", "S")))
    rename(join(root, name), join(root, name.replace("Episode ", "E")))
    rename(join(root, name), join(root, name.replace("episode ", "E")))
```

I'm getting an error saying "No such file or directory", though the error contains a file name given from walk(), so it is an actual file.

looking through the files, I see it works once every time before crashing.

any help? I've had a different script that does the same thing, only in a single directory, but I needed it to work in sub-directories too.

Comment: What happens, if a file contains two of the words, when it attempts to rename a second time?

Comment: I had a file named "season episode 1 2 3.txt" and it renamed it to "Sepisode 1 2 3.txt".
this doesn't really matter anymore, as khelwood's answer fixed the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to rename each file multiple times. After you rename it once, it won't have the name it had before, so you get a "no such file".
You should probably do all the modifications to the intended name before doing a single rename per file.

```
newname = name.replace("Season ", "S")
newname = newname.replace("season ", "S")
newname = newname.replace("Episode ", "E")
newname = newname.replace("episode ", "E")
rename(join(root, name), join(root, newname))
```

Comment: yep. that was the problem

Comment: `new_name = re.sub('season ', 'S', re.sub('episode ', 'E', name, re.I), re.I)`